# Execute external ajax function from inside jquery dialog button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, razor

I'm separating my code by creating a separate file for my jquery/ajax calls from the cshtml page.  My javascript file is already external.  The jquery/ajax file however is not being called and I wonder if my syntax is not correct.

calling CSHTML:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
   Savedialog = $("#Savedialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 225,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {
                //alert("test");
                SubmitTrxn;
            }


            ,Cancel: function () {
                Savedialog.dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function () {
            form[0].reset();
            allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
        }
    });`
```

Ajax.js content:

```
function SubmitTrxn() {
alert("test");

    TrxnName = $('#TrxnName').val().toString();
    TrxnDesc = $('#TrxnDesc').val().toString();
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/MyTransactions/DoesUserTransactionExistInDB",
            data: { 'TrxnName': TrxnName, 'TrxnDesc': TrxnDesc },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result === "True") {
                    Overwritedialog.dialog("open");
                }
                else {
                    SaveTrxn();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    Savedialog.dialog("close");

return;
```

Comment: you forgot to call the function: `SubmitTrxn` should be `SubmitTrxn()`

Comment: wow...I should go back to paper and pencil....